# Network down after suspend WIFI and Ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers, suspend, ethernet

Upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04 and installed CTparental DNS filtering, now no network after suspend neither WI-FI or Ethernet even though they show connected in the settings, although my Wi-Fi is excluded in suspend settings.

Device-1: Realtek RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8723ae 
Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169